# How can I share only one window with TeamViewer?

Tags: windows, window, teamviewer

I would like to share only one window through TeamViewer under Windows 7, not the entire desktop. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Use Presentation mode.

In Teamviewer 6 you can change from Remote Control to Presentation.
[image]

Click `Invite Participants` and you will get a text window with some canned text you can send to the the person you want to have watch.

> Hello,
>
> Please join the presentation on
>   http://www.teamviewer.com/download/version_6x/TeamViewerQJ.exe Use the
>   following data to log in:
>   ID: 357 621 583
>   Password: 6288
>
> Regards,

Once you start the presentation you will have a menu on the right hand side.
[image]

Under `Application Selection` you can un-check everything you want to hide. The `Local Monitor` window shows you what your viewers are watching.

Answer (score -1):

You can download a QuickSupport for their platform at the TeamViewer website.

Once it downloads, have them run the application and provide you with the ID and password it shows in the window.

All you need to do now is type in the session ID into your TeamViewer window or through the website quick connect.

When prompted type in the 4 digit password they give you.

If you are connecting to a machine with Windows logon enabled then drop down the advanced options and select Windows authentication. Put in your username and password on the computer and click log on.

A new window will open with the computer you are connecting to. Depending on the security settings, you may automatically have control of the remote machine upon connecting.

The TeamViewer window will have a bar across the top by default which will give you quick access to useful features. Remotely rebooting the machine, switching sides (presentation mode), disabling user input, and connection settings are all in the top menu for you on any platform.

Note: If you are curious, yes reboot in safemode works flawlessly. You have to reconnect after the reboot, and the user has to log in again, but otherwise it works without a hitch. This is great for remote virus scans.

If you know you will want to connect to the computer more than once it would be recommended to install the full version of TeamViewer. Luckily that is available in the menu as well.

Note: Some items will be grayed out if they are not available on your platform.

If you have access, you can also send or receive files to the remote machine from the top menu. Click on file transfer and a new window will pop up. Your local hard drive will show up on the left and the remote hard drive will be on the right. Click the appropriate send or receive button depending on what you are trying to do.

If you already have the computer set up as one of your partners you can also right click on the machine in your partner list to send/receive files without needing to go remote.

Once you disconnect from the user you will be prompted to add them to your partner list if they aren’t already there. Click yes if you plan on connecting to this computer again in the future.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to share only one window, not the entire desktop. I don't see why this description helps me.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Use WebEx for that.

Comment: -1 Yes you can, its called Single Window Mode.

Comment: Or at least it was in TV4, they added more functionality in TV6 so you can do one or many windows.