# Install VNC Server via RDP on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, vnc

I have a need to allow multiple users to view the same remote session on a Windows 2008 server. The server is cloud-based and is virtual. I have no physical access to it. I've tried several different combinations (Ultra VNC, Tight VNC, etc..) and tried to run as a service, but also as an application. It appears that installing via RDP somehow screws up how authentication is set up. I've tried various remedies in terms of setting the password after the install, including copying a registry key, also using a freeware tool called vncpwd.exe to no avail. In some variants of this I do get to a ctrl+alt-del login screen, but am thwarted by a cryptic UAC message that never allows me to login.

I'm not wedded to VNC, but I suspect that someone can walk me through setting this up properly.

Am looking for a "free" recipe to doing multiple viewers for same session. I am able to use web-based join.me, but it's not optimal. Running teamviewer on the server is not a "free" option.

Comment: "*a cryptic UAC message*" I'd love to have a look at that :)

Comment: Is this a terminal server? There is such thing as an install mode and execution mode on a terminal server. I have never seen it cause issues but maybe registering a service may need it to be in install mode.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx?cdsplit=C) instead of VNC. It's free for non commercial use and it has a presentation mode that does exactly what you are looking for. See [my answer to another question](https://superuser.com/questions/349946/how-can-i-share-only-one-window-with-teamviewer/390907#390907) to see what Presentation Mode looks like and how it works for inviting others to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Another Option for third party sofware would be [Anydesk](https://anydesk.com). I used it with a server without problems a while back.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!