# Is there any way to map a window to multiple X servers?

Tags: xorg

I want to share a window between several computers on the same LAN (only one of them controls this window, the others view it). At first, I tried VNC. But it's very slow. Is there any way to map the windows to multiple X servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install Teamviewer version 8 or higher in every system you want.
- Use **group sharing** feature.
- You can control permissions in the management console.

**PS**:You might have to activate the LAN mode in TeamViewer .

group sharing in action:[Youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8nrBBjFJTU)

Comment: I don't think it would be significantly faster than VNC, since they are both transferring screenshots between computers. And it seems impossible to share a single window instead of the whole screen.

Comment: you can't say that.VNC has some limitations in the protocol it uses:RFB,while team viewer is better than that as found here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498877/how-is-teamviewer-so-fast ,

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/349946/how-can-i-share-only-one-window-with-teamviewer